# Update an instance's property, from another instance

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I'm looking for the best way to update in object instance, for the example in this case `myParentObjects`'s name property. The only way I understand to achieve this would be to pass reference of the parent object to the child object instance as a parameter into either `new myChildObj(this,name)` in the constructor, or a method of the `myChildObj` instance like `myChildObj.updateParentProperty(name)`.

I can't imagine a child object nested 4-5 levels down, and having to update properties on it's parents passing `(parent1,parent2,parent3,etc)` it's params, that would be a managing nightmare! there must be a better way to update parent properties!

```
function myParentObj(){
    this.name = 'jordan'
    this.names = ['jordan','danny','cassie'];
    this.init=()=>{
       this.names.forEach((name)=>{
          var childObj = new myChildObj(this,name);
          childObj.updateParentProperty();
       })
    }
}
function myChildObj(parentObj,name){
    this.parent = parentObj;
    this.name = name;
    this.updateParentProperty=()=>{
        this.parent.name = this.name;
    };
}
function init(){
     var parentObj = new myParentObj();
     parentObj.init();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);
```

**Question:** What is the best method to update parent object parameters?

Comment: *"Is there any way to pass the `first` instance to the `second` instance so that it can manipulate the first's properties, other then `new mySecondObj(first)`"* -- that is literally exactly what you're doing

Comment: There are other methods, even without passing the first instance to your second instance (for example observer pattern or event bus).

Comment: @cyrix huh I'll have to check them out, you have any examples or links your could post as an answer

Comment: Why do you need do do this? This feels like a bit of an xy question. A 'child' probably shouldn't update a 'parent` a parent in the way you have shown. Maybe you want to pass in a callback and let the 'parent' decide what to do?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy its a basic example to demonstrate the point, I would never use something like this.

Comment: Why can't you just set `parent.name` right after you created the child object? The solution you thought up looks overengineered to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What puzzles me is this:

```
this.init=()=>{
   this.names.forEach((name)=>{
      var childObj = new myChildObj(this,name);
      childObj.updateParentProperty();
   })
}
```

because as soon as all three children are created, your parent will have a name of *cassie* (since that's the last child calling `updateParentProperty`). That and your tags is why I'm inclined to claim that you're looking for classical inheritance, like so:

**Classical inheritance**

```js
function myParentObj (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.names = ['jordan','danny','cassie'];
    this.init=()=>{
       this.names.forEach((name)=>{
          var childObj = new myChildObj(name);
          console.log(childObj);
       });
    }
}

function myChildObj (name) {
 myParentObj.call(this, name);
  
  // Other stuff, only available for myChildObj
}

function init(){
     var parentObj = new myParentObj();
     parentObj.init();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

var parent = new myParentObj();
console.log(parent);
```

Which would mean the child inherits properties from its parent, but would of course not update them for the parent when their own name changes.

**Some simple observer pattern**

Okay, your example just has a single property which change should be noticed. <strike>I think an observer pattern like in the example below is a bit too much, but for larger applications it's quite useful.</strike>. the observer pattern is not distinct to JavaScript only (see [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)). Basically, you have an object which changes shall be monitored (*observable*) and one or many objects which want to perform actions depending on these changes (*observers*). The implementation can be quite simple (like my demonstration) or really complex. The basic idea is for the observable to maintain a list of its observers. The example uses an own, simple implementation. There are also libraries available, we're using [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), which offers a MVVM structure for your page and can even update the DOM depending on changes.

```js
function myParentObj(){
    this.name = 'jordan'
    this.names = ['jordan','danny','cassie'];
    this.init=()=>{
       this.names.forEach((name)=>{
          var childObj = new myChildObj(name);
          childObj.subscribe('name', newValue => this.name = newValue);
       })
    }
}
function myChildObj(name){
    this.subscribers = {};
    
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
      set: newValue => {
        this._name = newValue;
        this.notify('name');
      },
      get: () => this._name
    });
    
    this.subscribe = function (prop, callback) {
      if (!this.subscribers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        this.subscribers[prop] = [];
      }
      
      this.subscribers[prop].push(callback);
    };
    
    this.notify = function (prop) {
      if (this.subscribers[prop]) {
        this.subscribers[prop].forEach(callback => callback(this[prop]));
      }
    };
}
function init(){
     var parentObj = new myParentObj();
     parentObj.init();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);

var parent = new myParentObj();
var child = new myChildObj('bob');
child.subscribe('name', newName => parent.name = newName);
console.log(parent.name);
child.name = 'cassie';
console.log(parent.name);
```

**Using `Object.assign`**

You could also use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which will copy all enumerable properties from one object to another. You should note, though, that it will copy *all* properties, even those you might not want to change.

```js
function myParentObj(){
    this.name = 'jordan'
    this.names = ['jordan','danny','cassie'];
    this.init=()=>{
       this.names.forEach((name)=>{
          var childObj = new myChildObj(this,name);
          childObj.updateParentProperty();
       })
    }
}
function myChildObj(name){
    this.name = name;
}

var parent = new myParentObj();
var child = new myChildObj('cassie');
Object.assign(parent, child);
console.log(child);
```

Comment: The example was just to demonstrate the concept of parent/child. Your first and third examples are useless, I'm curious about your observer pattern, can you give me a better use case example then using the example I used.

Comment: @JordanDavis I updated the text a little. Since the observer pattern itself is not distinct to JS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), I can think of thousands of examples. It is a very common concept. If you enter "observer pattern" into a search engine, you'll find much more examples than I could offer.

Comment: It sounds like the only case use for observer patterns would be if your using WebSockets (or Node.js) or else you might as well pass parent in a param?

Comment: The observer pattern is useful whenever some object must do something according to a change of some state in some other object. This may as well include complex chains (a bool gets true, A notifies B about it, B fetches data from the server and notifies C, C does something with it...). Fair enough, you may as well implement such behaviour with passing around instances as parameters. But as soon as you have something like "D subscribes A, B and C and C subscribes E..." it gets dirty (such relationships are quite common).

Answer (score 2):

#### Classical inheritance

I see you mixed in some ES6, so you might be looking for an answer using the [ES6 standards of object-oriented inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) like so:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(name = 'jordan') {
    this.name = name
    this.names = ['jordan', 'danny', 'cassie']
  }
  
  init() {
    return this.names.map((name) => {
      return new Child(name)
    })
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name)
    
    // other stuff for Child
  }
}

let parent = new Parent()
console.log(parent)
let children = parent.init()
children.forEach((child) => console.log(child))
```

In ES5, [inheritance was usually implemented like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#With_a_constructor) instead, though this is not *exactly* what ES6 `class` does, since ES6 does things like making instance methods non-enumerable, etc.

```js
function Parent(name) {
  name = arguments.length > 0 ? name : 'jordan'

  this.name = name
  this.names = ['jordan', 'danny', 'cassie']
}

// member methods
Parent.prototype = {
  init: function init() {
    return this.names.map(function (name) {
      return new Child(name)
    })
  }
}

function Child(name) {
  // basically, super(name)
  Parent.call(this, name)
  
  // other stuff for Child
}


// extending Parent
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
Parent.prototype.constructor = Parent

var parent = new Parent()
console.log(parent)
var children = parent.init()
children.forEach(function (child) { console.log(child) })
```

Below is almost exactly the ES5 equivalent for the ES6 code in the first example:

```js
function Parent() {
  var name = arguments.length > 0 && name !== undefined ? name : 'jordan'

  this.name = name
  this.names = ['jordan', 'danny', 'cassie']
}

// member methods
Object.defineProperties(Parent.prototype, {
  init: {
    configurable: true,
    value: function init() {
      return this.names.map(function (name) {
        return new Child(name)
      })
    },
    writable: true
  }
})

function Child(name) {
  // basically, super(name)
  Parent.call(this, name)
  
  // other stuff for Child
}


// extending Parent
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    configurable: true,
    value: Child,
    writable: true
  }
})

var parent = new Parent()
console.log(parent)
var children = parent.init()
children.forEach(function (child) { console.log(child) })
```

#### EventEmitter

After looking at the comments below the other answer, it appears you are most interested in observer-type patterns. [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), defined natively in Node.js, is the most widely used implementation of the observer pattern. Below is a polyfill demo of it for client-side JavaScript:

```js
class Parent extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(name = 'jordan') {
    super()

    this.name = name
  }
}

class Child {
  constructor(parent, name = parent.name) {
    this.parent = parent
    this._name = name
  }

  set name(name) {
    console.log('setting child name')

    this._name = name

    this.parent.emit('name', name)
  }
  
  get name() {
    return this._name
  }
}

let parent = new Parent()

parent.on('name', function (name) {
  console.log('setting parent name')

  this.name = name
}.bind(parent))

let child = new Child(parent)

console.log('parent', parent.name)
console.log('child',  child.name)

child.name = 'danny'

console.log('parent', parent.name)
console.log('child',  child.name)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mudge/5830382/raw/a4bc230f5bce01ea9a34b0d42247256531b97945/eventemitter.js"></script>
```

#### Proxy

Another neat API that JavaScript has is called [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which allows metaprogramming, that is, redefining how JavaScript works in isolated cases:

```js
var parent = {}
var child = {}

var proxy = new Proxy(child, {
  set: (target, property, value) => {
    // target === child
    target['child-' + property] = typeof value + ' ' + value
    parent['parent-' + property] = typeof value + ' ' + value
    
    return value
  }
})

proxy.name = 'jordan'
proxy.age = 54

console.log(parent)
console.log(child)
```